# Get Lavavel (5) data without direct relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have an app consisting of these tables

- users
- channels (with `user_id` foreign key to user)
- playlists (with `user_id` foreign key to user and foreign `channel_id` to channels)
- tracks (with `playlist_id` foreign key to playlists BUT NOT a `user_id` foreign key)

`User` model is defined with:

```
public function channels()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Channel');
}
```

`Channel` model is defined with:

```
public function playlists()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Playlist');
}
```

(and a `$this->belongsTo('App\User')`)

`Playlist` model is defined with:

```
public function tracks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Track');
}
```

(and a `$this->belongsTo('App\Channel')`)

`Track` model is defined with:

```
public function playlist()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Playlist');
}
```

Now when listing the tracks in the specific Playlist I do this:

```
function list($playlist) {
    $tracks = Track::with('playlist')->get();
    return response()->json($tracks);
}
```

This works correctly at the page `http://.../tracks/2` (where 2 is the playlist id) but if the user changes 2 into 3 he can potentially see the tracks in the playlist #3 which may not be his. So How do I get the user id from the playlist to show only the tracks belonging to a playlist which the user actually has?

Comment: Having a user_id field on the channels table and playlist_id on the tracks table means a channel will only have one user and a track will only have one playlist, is this correct?

Comment: Look for hasManyTrough on Laravel Docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your given code, it looks like you're not actually loading the playlist as specified by the ID in your URL. `$playlist` here should be `2` with your example URL (`http://.../tracks/2`):

```
function list($playlist) {
    $tracks = Track::with('playlist')->get();
    return response()->json($tracks);
}
```

You're simply loading *all* tracks in your entire system, eager loading in their respective `Playlist` objects.

Assuming with that URL, you want to show the tracks for playlist 2, if and only if it belongs to the authenticated user, what you *should* do is find the playlist by its ID, authorise that the `Playlist` belongs to the logged in user and then load in its `tracks` using the relation:

```
public function list($id)
{
    // Find a playlist with the given ID, or 404 if none could be found.
    $playlist = Playlist::findOrFail($id);

    // If the playlist does not belong to the user, throw an AuthorizationException.
    if ($playlist->user_id != auth()->user()->id) {
        throw new AuthorizationException();
    }

    // Return a response, passing through the tracks belonging to the playlist.
    return response()->json($playlist->tracks);
}
```

A better way of handling the authorisation would be to use [Laravel's built in authorisation features](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization), most notably [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#creating-policies). This would allow you to separate your authorisation logic from your controller and keep all your authorisation logic in the same/similar place:

- Create a policy, using `php artisan make:policy PlaylistPolicy` which would create a class `App\Policies\PlaylistPolicy`.
- In that policy, simply define a method which denotes the action you're authorising against your playlists. In this example, you're authorising whether or not a user can *view* a given playlist, so `view` would be my suggestion of method name here.
- That method would accept 2 parameters, the authenticated user, and the `Playlist` object that you're interested in:

  ```
  public function view(User $user, Playlist $playlist)
  {
      //
  }
  ```
- Within that method all you need to do is add some logic that determines if the given user (the logged in user) has access to be able to *view* the given `Playlist`. The method should return `true` if the user has access or `false` if not.

  ```
  public function view(User $user, Playlist $playlist)
  {
      return $user->id === $playlist->user_id;
  }
  ```
- Now you just need to register the policy in your `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider`. You just need to map the `Playlist` model to the `PlaylistPolicy` by adding to the `$policies` property and you should be good to go.

  ```
  protected $policies = [
      Playlist::class => PlaylistPolicy::class
  ];
  ```
- Now instead of that if statement in your controller you can simply use the `authorize` method, which should be present on your controller (as long as the `AuthorizesRequests` trait is `use`d).

  ```
  public function list($id)
  {
      $playlist = Playlist::findOrFail($id);

      $this->authorize('view', $playlist);

      return response()->json($playlist->tracks);
  }
  ```

Comment: `list` is a reserved word, there's a built-in function [list()](https://php.net/list).

Comment: You can use `list` as a method name in PHP 7 (Not sure exactly which version). However, `list` comes from the OP's code.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry!

Comment: No worries, you're definitely correct for slightly earlier versions of PHP though :]